# why webread fails but urlread works?

Tags: matlab

`webread` is supposed to be better than `urlread`, but the following website is not properly read by webread, but it can be read successfully by urlread

```
webread('https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.6.8cca20c0b2dbKh&id=567338689808&cm_id=140105335569ed55e27b&abbucket=9&skuId=3614502097821');

urlread('https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.6.8cca20c0b2dbKh&id=567338689808&cm_id=140105335569ed55e27b&abbucket=9&skuId=3614502097821');
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please define "not properly"

Comment: Not properly means the website contents are not fully read，thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues and contacted Mathworks in May 2017. They admitted that sometimes `urlread` works better than `webread` because of 'server side issues which leads to `webread` not being able to correctly acquire the data from the server in question. 
The documentation basically just recommends using the newer functions, but since in this particular case there is a conflict between the newer functions and the server we should ignore that recommendation.'

Comment: Thanks, but there are still some problems with the urlread, urlread cannnot fully read content from the website even if it is better than the webread。